# Incomplete solution of a problem in Qualitative ODE.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I can't to complete my solution in the following problem:

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be $C^1$ and $q\in\mathbb{R}$
>   such that $f(q) = 0$ and $f'(q) >0$. Consider the Cauchy problem
>
> $(\star)\quad\left\{ \begin{array}{l} \displaystyle{ x'=\frac{f(x)}{t}}, \quad t>0 \\ 
> x(t_0) = x_0. 
> \end{array}\right. $
>
> Denote by $\phi(t;t_0,x_o)$ the maximal solution of $(\star)$. Show
>   that there exist $(t_0,x_o)$, with $t_0>0$, $x_0 \neq q$, such that
>
> $$\lim_{t\to 0}\phi(t;t_0,x_0) = q.$$

Here is my partial solution in step by step:

(1) We have $\phi(t;t_0,x_0)$ is defined for all $t>0$, basically because $F(t,x) = f(x)/t$ is $C^1$ in the second variable (here there exist a long argument, but simple).

(2) For all $t,t_0>0$, we have that

$ \quad\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
\phi(t;t_0,x_0)>q,\quad \text{if } x_0>q,\\
\phi(t;t_0,x_0)=q,\quad \text{if } x_0=q,\\
\phi(t;t_0,x_0)<q,\quad \text{if } x_0<q.
\end{array} \right.$

(3) Since $f(q) = 0$ and $f'(q) >0$, there exist $\epsilon >0$ such that f is increasing in $(q-\epsilon,q+\epsilon)$. Furthermore,

$\quad\left\{ \begin{array}{l} 
f(x)>0,\quad\text{if }x\in(q,q+\epsilon) \\
f(x)<0,\quad\text{if }x\in(q-\epsilon,q) \\
\end{array}\right.
$

(4) For $t_0>0,x_0\neq q$ given, consider $\phi(t) = \phi(t;t_0,x_0)$. Suppose that $\phi(t)>q$, for all $t>0$. Let $t_1 = \inf\{t>0\,;\; \phi(t)=q+\epsilon\}$ (possibly, $t_1 = \infty$). Suppose tha $t_1>0$. We have, by (2) and (3), that

$$\phi'(t) = \frac{f(\phi(t))}{t} > 0, \forall t\in(0,t_1)$$

Thus $\phi(t)$ is increasing in $(0,t_1)$.

When $\phi(t) < q$, and $t_1 = \inf\{t>0\,;\; \phi(t)=q-\epsilon\}$ (possibly, $t_1 = \infty$), we have $\phi(t)$ non-increasing in $(0,t_1)$.

(5) By (4), once $\phi(t)$ is monotone, continuous and bounded (near of $0$), we have that exist the limit
$$\lim_{t\to 0} \phi(t) =:\phi(0).$$

(6) By (5), we have that
$$ \lim_{t\to 0} \phi'(t) = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(\phi(t))}{t} = \infty,$$
once $f$ is continuous.

How can I to complete the solution of the problem? Am I in the wrong way? If yes, can you to show a solution for me?

Thanks!